# How to replace part of a URL with regex

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I need to remove part of a URL with a regex.
From the words: http or https to the word .com.
And it can be several times in one string.
Can anyone help me with this?

For example a string:
"The request is:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions%22)
After the removal - "The request is:/questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex that performed the deletion perfectly is: (@"\w+://[^/$]*")
with replace "".

Something like that:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+:\/\/[^\/$]*");
regex.Replace(url, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `re.sub()` function from the regex package. Alternatively if your working with python you can use `urlparse` package to extract different parts of the url and concatenate it to the prefix you want.

Comment: re.sub() is good if I have the same URL every time.
I'm looking for something for a all the URL's, which will delete from 1 word to another word.